# Vue - component background image url error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My code that calls set background image to component:

```
style() {
  return {
    "background-image": `url(${require(`../../../assets/images/${this
      .last_result}.png`)})`
  };
},
```

the correct url should be

> ../../../assets/images/AR.png

but instead the the console shows error of the url, it becomes calling

> /assets/images/AR0.2514806280000456da85c5fNaNpng

I couldnt find whats the issue. Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows.

```
style() {
  return {
    "background-image": `url(${require(`@/assets/images/${this
      .last_result}.png`)})`
  };
},
```

Try using obsolute path.

your obsolute path would be `@/assets/images/` if your assets folder exists in `src/assets/images/`.

And if you want to user relative path refer to this `../../../assets/images/` path from your current component.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm not sure with obsolute path, but when I change to `@` , when compile, it expect it to be a dependency

Comment: @hatched Can you tell me the path where you are trying to include the image?

Comment: src/controller/component/assets/images/AR.png

Comment: @hatched tell me the file path of the component that has the above code?